# ESRI Runtime Geodatabase Shape storage

Tags: sqlite, mobile, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net, binary

Does anyone out there know the geometry storage encoding for ESRI's Runtime Geodatabase (`.sqlite`) format? aka mobile geodatabase.

There are `'GDB_ tables'`, `'st_ tables'`, `'RTREE indexes'` and other fairly standard geodatabase bits, but I'm having trouble identifying the binary encoding of the SHAPE column in the feature tables. It's not WKB, it appears to have a very standard header and a consistent 'footer' character (I think).

These are XY points stored in 4326.

[image: example]

Comment: The earlier version stored json in that field, so I tried BSON (Newtonsoft.Json.Bson), but it complained about `MapPoint` not having a constructor when I tried `serializer.Deserialize<MapPoint>`. Anyone remember what the json for shape used to look like in sqlite?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://github.com/rouault/dump_gdbtable/wiki/FGDB-Spec#gdb-files